# MVC partially restrict view access to users that are not admins

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to restrict access to certain parts of a view based on a Access Restriction? Currently I can limit users from getting to pages by doing this in the controller

`[RestrictAccess(restriction = AccessRestrictions.Admin)]`

But is it possible for me restrict a certain aspect from the page while still allowing other users access to the page?

Here is model that checks if user has access

```
 public enum AccessRestrictions
    {      
        [Display(Name = "Admin")]
        Admin
    }
    public class userAccess
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public AccessRestrictions restriction { get; set; }
        public bool allow { get; set; }
        public int userID { get; set; }

    }
    public class configDetails
    {
        public int ID {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string Value {get;set;}
        public bool deleted {get;set;}
        public DateTime updateTime { get; set; }

    }
    public class Config
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Configuration Date")]
        public DateTime TargetDate { get; set; }

           [Display(Name = "Enable Access Restrictions")]
        public bool restrictAccess { get; set; }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have follow view

```
<div id="CallList">
  @Html.Action("List","Call",new {id=Model.id})
</div>

<div class="Order">
  @Html.Action("Create","Order",new {id=Model.id})
</div>
```

With follow actions:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "manager, caller")] //if a user is not 'manager' or 'caller'
public PartialViewResult List()        // nothing is shown
{
  //...private 
  return PartialView();
}

[Authorize(Roles = "manager, admin")]
public PartialViewResult Create()
{
  //...private 
  return PartialView();
}
```

Then you can limit access via this ext. method

```
public static  MvcHtmlString ActionBaseRole(this HtmlHelper value, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues , IPrincipal user)
 {     
   bool userHasRequeredRole = false;
   Type t = Type.GetType((string.Format("MyProject.Controllers.{0}Controller",controllerName))); // MyProject.Controllers... replace on you namespace
   MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod(actionName);
   var attr = (method.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(AuthorizeAttribute), true) as AuthorizeAttribute);
   if (attr != null)
   {
      string[] methodRequeredRoles = attr.Roles.Split(',');
      userHasRequeredRole = methodRequeredRoles.Any(r => user.IsInRole(r.Trim())); // user roles check in depends on implementation authorization in you site  
                                                                                            // In a simple version that might look like                                                                         
   }
   else userHasRequeredRole = true; //method don't have Authorize Attribute
   return userHasRequeredRole ? value.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues) : MvcHtmlString.Empty; 
 }
```

Example of usage:

```
@Html.ActionBaseRole("List","Call",new {id=Model.id},User)
```

Note your security attributes are different but I think you can easy replace it.

Comment: Thanks! I have been looking at similar things to what you have put. I'm just confused on how to translate my security attributes to have it work. I updated my question with the model that checks user access

Comment: replace AuthorizeAttribute to AccessRestrictions and retrieve value

Comment: Hmm when I added that it was littered with errors, likely because I'm not understanding whats happening correctly. I'm new to MVC so excuse my ignorance, I appreciate the help though